# Javascript create new 2d array of a 2d array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've 2d array that is formatted wrong, something like this below:

```
[['a','b','c'],['d','f','e'],['g','h','i']]
```

I want it to be converted like this:

```
[['a','d','g'],['b','f','h'],['c','e','i']]
```

What's the best way to this? I can't find the solution.

Comment: In what basis you want to replacing the chars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach.  I also added the `Array.from({length: array.length}, (value, key) => key)` to have more dynamic code.

```js
const array = [['a','b','c'],['d','f','e'],['g','h','i']];

const mapped = array.map((item, index, arr) => Array.from({length: array.length}, (value, key) => key).map(i => arr[i][index]));

console.log(mapped);
```

Comment: @RalphJanssen If it works, accept the answer so others know

Answer (score 0):

You could transposte the array by swapping the indices for a new result.

```js
var array =[['a','b','c'],['d', 'f', 'e'], ['g', 'h', 'i']],
    result = array.reduce(function (r, a, i) {
        a.forEach(function (v, j) {
            (r[j] = r[j] || [])[i] = v;
        });
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a=[['a','b','c'],['d','f','e'],['g','h','i']]

// initialising b
b= [['a','b','c'],['d','f','e'],['g','h','i']]

//Talking transpose
for(i =0;i<3;i++){
    for(j=0;j<3;j++){
        b[i][j] = a[j][i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

double map one liner solution. Assumes outer array length and inner array lengths are the same

```js
var data = [['a','b','c'],['d','f','e'],['g','h','i']]

var res= data.map((a, i) => data.map((arr)=>arr[i]));

console.log(res)
```